# Pointer manipulation and type casting

Tags: c, pointers, macros, malloc

From the custom memory allocator for malloc, consider this two macros:

```
#define GET_HDR(bp) (*(int *)((int *)(bp) – 1))
#define GET_HDR(bp) (*(int *)((char **)(bp) – 1))
```

Here `bp` is a `void` pointer.

`GET_HDR(bp)` is used to get the content of the `HEADER` which is a 4-byte block stored just before void pointer `bp`. Here the 1st macro takes void pointer `bp`, typecasts it into int and subtract 1 to take pointer 4-bytes back so that it points to the `HEADER` block and then dereference the pointer to give value of `HEADER` block.

But how does the 2nd macro do it? How pointer are manipulated to reach `HEADER` block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro likely assumes the size of a `char *` is the same as an `int`.

```
(
    *(int *)(       /* Treat result as pointer to int and dereference */
      (char **)(bp) /* bp is cast to a pointer to (char *) */
      – 1           /* take bp back sizeof(char *) bytes (presumably also 4) */
    )
)
```

Comment: the line `(char **)(bp)` , `bp` is a single pointer (i.e `void*`), is it okay to cast it into type `void**` ?? shouldn't that be an error?

Comment: You can cast to anything you want in C without causing a compile time error. Whether it will work correctly is dependent on what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 1):

A *pointer-is-a-pointer*, but pointer arithmetic depends on the `type`. If `int` and `char *` are not the same size, then the macros are not offsetting by the same amount in memory when subtracting 1. When you then cast again to `*(int *)` to obtain the value, you can end up with different results.

You must be careful when using pointer arithmetic. Problems come in if `int` and `char *` are different on the system. For instance on `x86_64` pointer size is `8-bytes` and the size of an `int` is `4-bytes`. On `x86` pointer size is `4-bytes` and the size of an `int` is also `4-bytes`.

When you cast `(int *)(bp) - 1` you are asking for the *pointer-before*-`bp` (or `4-bytes` before `bp` on any system with a `4-byte int` -- that covers most systems). However, casting`(char **)(bp) - 1` on `x86_64` asks for the pointer `8-bytes` before `bp` compared to `4-bytes` before on `x86`. This can lead to issues.

You must also be careful in casting to differing types in macros and avoid violating the *strict aliasing* rules. See sections `6.5.6` and `6.5.7` of the C-standard. Not implicated here, but if you are relying on multiple casts in macros, you may mask violations.

Comment: _"However, casting(char **)(bp) - 1 on x86_64 asks for the pointer 8-bytes before bp compared to 4-bytes before on x86."_ `bp` is of type `void*`, so it shoud be casted into `<datatype>*` right? Why/How does `<datatype>**` work? I know its a noob question, but it has got me confused.